# NoClassDefFoundError using Command Prompt

Tags: java, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I've been trying to fix this error for the past 30 minutes but I am new to java and I can't find what's wrong by Googling.
I've tried setting my classpath, tried java and java -cp . but no luck.
I think maybe it's something in my code?
I am still using notepad and my .java and .class files are both in the folder where I've set my classpath to.

This is the error I get:
http://gyazo.com/dfa7d2c9b319bfa2f4bbf5990cf43ab6.png

C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP>java -cp . Thuisopdracht
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Thuisopdracht (wrong
name: userinput/Thuisopdracht)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

This is my code:

```
package userinput;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Thuisopdracht {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    List<String> lijstKaarten = new LinkedList<String>();
    lijstKaarten.add("Harten");
    lijstKaarten.add("Ruitens");
    lijstKaarten.add("Klaveren");
    lijstKaarten.add("Schuppen");

Random rand = new Random();
String stringcomputerKeuze = "";
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter != 5) {
        int computerKeuze = rand.nextInt(lijstKaarten.size());
        stringcomputerKeuze = lijstKaarten.get(computerKeuze);
        counter++;
    }


double computerNummer = (Math.random() * (13 - 1)) + 1;

String typeKaart;
typeKaart = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welk type kaart kies je?");

String kaartNummer;
kaartNummer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Welke kaartnummer kiest u? (1-13)");

int intKaartNummer = Integer.parseInt(kaartNummer);

System.out.println("De computer koos " + stringcomputerKeuze + " " + computerNummer);
System.out.println("Jij koos " + typeKaart + " " + kaartNummer);


}
```

}

Comment: Use Eclipse (or any other integrated IDE you can get your hands on). Even Notepad++ is a **huge** difference, but still not quite the one I'd use for Java. Also, please cut and paste the error message in the question too.

Comment: I use Notepad++ atm, I'll use Netbeans or Eclipse once I understand Java a little more.
Sorry I forgot you can copy from cmd, I'll edit the OP.

Comment: Check if file Thuisopdracht.java is really on path C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP\userinput\Thuisopdracht.java. Check also spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use package name `userinput`

Use `userinput.Thuisopdracht`

```
 java -cp . userinput.Thuisopdracht
```

Comment: your screenshot shows that `java - cp . userinput.Thuisopdracht`. "-" and "cp" are separated

Comment: use `-cp` instead `- cp`

Comment: Sorry, that was sloppy.
I get a:
Error: Could not find or load main class userinput.Thuisopdracht

Comment: give me your java path and `.class` path

Comment: In C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP
So is Thuisopdracht.java, I've tried putting Thuisopdracht.java in a new map called userinput as someone here suggested ^

Comment: well, you didnt compile your code. You need 1st off compile it, and `Thuisopdracht.class` should be generated. after run `java -cp . `

Comment: I have compiled my Thuisopdracht.java using javac Thuisopdracht.java after a long session of getting errors out yesterday, it's called Thuisopdracht.class

Comment: It's in C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP
By now I have also copied both of them to C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP\Userinput to avoid confusion on where to put them.

Comment: 1st off change folder name from `Userinput` to `userinput`. After, go to `C:\Users\Karel\Dropbox\OOP` and from there run `java -cp .......`

Comment: Thank you, my program ran succesfully.